# Insert "xyz" to a line that starts with "abc"

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I am not used to using `sed` for anything and I am not sure if this is even possible.

I need to do the following in a text file:

1. Find a line that starts with "abc"
2. Insert "xyz" between the "b" and the "c" of said line
3. Replace the original line with the new line

One *huge* caveat: If there is not a line that starts with "abc", I need to insert a line, and it must be inserted before a line that starts with "def".

Comment: Have you tried any code up to this point?

Answer (score 2):

(1) The first part of your question can be done like:

```
sed -i .bak 's/^abc/abxyzc/' input_file
```

(`-i .bak` for editing in-place, and creating a backup file with extension ".bak")

(2) The second part, inserting a line before another line (not including the condition about "abc" missing), can be done like:

```
sed -i .bak 's/^def/NEW_LINE\ndef/' input_file
```

I don't think you can write "if cond do (1) else do (2)" as a one-liner. Write a simple script for that...

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s/(^|\n)(ab)(c)/\1\2xyz\3/;t;s/(^|\n)(def)/\n\1\2/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory. Substitute `xyz` between `ab` and `c` at the start of a line. If this substitution is carried out break out of further processing. Otherwise substitute a newline before `def` at the start of a line.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a little complex with `sed`. If you can use `awk` then the following should work. This does two passes on the file. If it finds `/^abc/` it does what you ask. If `/^abc/` is not found then it looks for `/def/` and inserts `xyz` on a line before it.

```
awk '
NR==FNR && /^abc/{ 
    found = 1
    $0 = substr($0,0,2) "xyz" substr($0,3)
    lines[NR] = $0
    next
}
NR==FNR {
    lines[NR] = $0 
    next
}
!found && /^def/ {
    lines[FNR-1] = lines[FNR-1] "\nabc"
}
END {
    for(line=1; line<=FNR; line++) 
        print lines[line]
}' file{,} > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Just as an curiosity, you can change `file file` to `file{,}`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    /^def/ && !inserted {print "abxyzc"; forced = 1}
    /^abc/ && !forced   {sub(/^abc/,"abxyzc"); inserted = 1}
    1
    END {if ((!inserted) && (!forced)) print "abxyzc"}
' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If there's no "abc" **and** no "def", I print the modified "abc" line at the end. You did not specify this case.